# Options for universal pick lists?

Tags: picklist

Is there any strategy for implementing global lookup lists (universal pick lists) ?

There is a [long standing request (for 7 years)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrfBAAS&sort=2) for this, and it is something that I am used to having in Dynamics CRM.

Is there some other way it can be done? i.e. through a web service call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can think of is using a custom object to hold all of the picklist values. Your other objects would use filtered lookups, but you are limited to how many active lookup filters you can use, on a per-object basis.

Comment: Yes, this is also something that can be done with Dynamics CRM. The main issue with this approach is that if you have a lot of global picklists then you will need a new custom object with relations for each one. If it is just a few picklists then it is workable.

Comment: You can do one custom object for all of them, as long as you can filter them by a type field.

Comment: But this will complicate some tasks, such as default values and record type filters, but also relaxes other limits, such as the maximum number of pick list values pretty field.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still looking for something, it appears this is now in pilot in the winter 16 [release](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_global_picklists.htm)!

> Share Picklists Across Objects and Fields with Global Picklists
>   (Pilot)
>
> Efficiently reuse a single list of values for multiple custom picklist
>   fields. Global picklists make it easy to share picklists across
>   objects by letting you create picklist fields based on a master list
>   of values. And, they keep your picklist data clean by preventing users
>   from adding erroneous or redundant values through the API. This
>   feature is available in both Lightning Experience and Salesforce
>   Classic.

Update: still pilot but now also available in dev orgs and sandboxes by default in [Spring 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_global_picklists_open_pilot.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom setting with all your pick list values n use a lookup from wherever u need.

Comment: Creating as a custom setting has limited use in the standard UI usual best practise is to use a custom object which can be accessible in code as well as in the standard UI.

Comment: @Francis A list custom setting seems like an obvious choice here and can certainly be accessed in code. What exactly makes using a custom object better?

Comment: @francis would like to understand further from you.

Comment: Yes custom settings can be used if they are exclusively going to be used in code but the question was "universal picklists". IE How would an admin then create a field on an object that has the picklist values stored "centrally" in a custom setting? The only way to achieve a centralised list that could support both the declarative and code worlds would be to hold it as an object and use lookup relationship fields. Ok multi-select picklists are different kettle of fish. But even objects are not ideal but better, even siebel has something similar to MSDynamics but looks like SF is working on it.

Answer (score -2):

@andrew there is a new app called Universal Picklists that might help solve your problem.  You can manage picklists across multiple objects from one location.  Hope this helps.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000pvmXEAQ

Comment: Hi, without sharing some personal experiences or explaining how this app solves the issue this is purely seen by advertising, which may be cause for deletion or downvotes. You can still update your answer to include more info if you'd like.